# User's membership in active directory group not showing through powerbroker

Tags: linux, active-directory, authentication, groups

We're using Powerbroker open (Version 7.1) to authenticate Active Directory users into our Oracle linux (V6.4)  (servers.

I have a user "Joe Blow", who was added to the Active Directory group, "unix_xyz" today. (for users of the xyx application).  I wanted to verify that Joe was correctly seen on the linux server, so I ran the PB utility list-groups-by-user to verify.  The group does not show up in Joe's list of group memberships.

I checked a second server in the domain.  Joe's group membership shows properly.  I've run the "enum-groups" utility to see if the server saw the group in the AD domain.  It's visible.
A second user added at the same time with the same groups is listed correctly.

I've deleted the powerbroker cache on the user in question a couple of times, and restarted the lwsmd daemon a couple of times to no avail.

Does anyone know of a way to force Joe's credentials through again so his group memberships are seen properly?

TIA
Dave